# Does the series of the reciprocals of Sophie Germain primes converge?

Tags: number-theory, analysis

Yesterday when reading Landau's Elementary Number Theory, I came across Brun's theorem which states that the reciprocals of twin primes add up to a finite sum (the series converges), and this made me wonder if the same is true for Sophie Germain primes (the reciprocals add up to a finite sum). But I cannot Google out anything. Can anyone give an answer or point me to some references? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The same sieve methods of Brun used to show the result on the twin primes can be used to estimate that, for any fixed $k$ and $a$ coprime positive integers with different parity, the number of primes $p < x$ for which $kp+a$ is prime is bounded above by $C x/(\log x)^2$ for some constant $C$. This implies that the sum of the reciprocals of that primes is convergent.

In fact, it is expected that the number of Sophie Germain primes less than $x$ is asymptotically equal to the number of twin primes less than $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask for some spelling out of your 2nd paragraph or some references such as survey articles?

Comment: Xarles is saying it works the same for $p,p+2$ both primes and $p,2p+1$ both primes. Estimating $O(x/\log^2 x)$ for the number of twin primes is the Brun sieve, you'll find a lot of resources about it. The random model for the primes applies the same way for the twin primes constant and the Sophie Germain primes constant, check [here](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?43,1845512,1847344#msg-1847344) for an elementary way to derive it